# MST Hadoop IntWritable

Tags: java, hadoop, minimum-spanning-tree

I'm Japanese college student.
So,　I may not be able to speak English well.

Now,I study MST,Hadoop.
I was referring to this [page MST](http://hadooptutorial.wikispaces.com/Sorting+feature+of+MapReduce).
But, I want to MST in multiple rounds.
I want to output each of the edge rather than issue a total edge.

So
Line 112-115

```
String strKey = new String();
strKey += inputKey;
Text outputKey = new Text(strKey);
```

~~~~~

```
String strKey = new String();
strKey = Integer.toString(inputKey);
Text outputKey = new Text(strKey);
```

~~~~~
I want to like this.

However, there are undefined constructor or type mismatch, it does not work.

Could you tell me the improvement?

I think of MST
1 rounds
G = (V,E)
V=V1∪V2...∪Vk
V1 and V2 run the this program.(In parallel,V2 and V3...)

2~multiple rounds
Run the program again each result, making MST finally.

Comment: What is the type of `inputKey`? `Text`?

Comment: Thank you.inputKey is Text.